# What's the difference between something and some thing?

Tags: difference

I was reading my English textbook and found written "*some thing*" in a sentence. Is there any difference between "**something**" and "**some thing**"? Is it a misprint or true? Here is the sentence:

> Hunger means, when you have had ***some thing*** to eat at least as much
>   again.

*(from essay: Hunger and Population Explosion by Anna Mckenzie)*

Which one will be correct in this context? Some thing or something

Comment: This is evidently a pretty poor textbook, since I can't even figure out what that sentence is trying to convey.

Comment: @Matt - That sentence was not written by the author of the book; it was a sample excerpt taken from an [outside source](http://www.sheir.org/hunger-and-population-explosion.html). That said, I agree with your assessment – it's not an exemplary sentence unless the authors and editors were looking for samples of poor writing.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, there is no difference.  ["Some thing" is much much less common than "something"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=something%2C%20some%20thing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), however, so the only reason to write it as two separate words is to emphasize the "some" part (in contrast to "any" or "no" thing):

> I want to get her *some* thing for Valentines Day, but not just anything.
>   It has to be *something* she would like.

Another possibility is that the writer uses separate words to emphasize the *"thing"* part (in contrast to some *one*).  To quote Jim Carrey quoting Shatner from an old "Twilight Zone":

> [There's someone on the wing!  Some ... *thing*!](https://youtu.be/xVxuHqmNpbI?t=54)

Still, it is rare and the example you quote is more likely a typo than intentional.

Comment: A similar case is **maybe** verses **may be**. In both cases the words were used together so much, writers ended up treating the word pairs as single words. Yet cases exist where we still need to treat them as separate words. *It may be true, but I don't want to believe it.* or *Some **one** is at my door, but some **thing** is in my closet.* // Check the ngram for **any thing, anything** if you want to see a word pair die.

Comment: @RichF  Yes, good point.  Some thing might be used to emphasize the "thing" part.  I'll edit my answer to include this.